# Range-Input-Field becomes another style by setting border-color (FF)

Tags: html, css, firefox

i found a nice bug in Firefox (I'm using FF38ESR):

When I give an Range-Input-Field an border-color, it becomes another style.

[image: two range-inputs]

```
<style>
#r1{
    border-color: red;
}
</style>

<input id="r1" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="10" />
<input id="r2" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="10" />
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3jkxjwj/1/)

Is this behavior known?

Comment: That's is very odd. I would say its a FireFox bug